# start-stop-daemon freebsd

Tags: freebsd

Have a line in sh script starting service from rc.d

```
start-stop-daemon --quiet --start --background --chuid "$USER" --exec /usr/local/bin/env -- $ARGS RETVAL=$?
```

it returns

```
/etc/rc.d/spat: start-stop-daemon: not found
/etc/rc.d/spat: --exec: not found
```

There is no start-stop-daemon ?

Comment: FreeBSD has `daemon(8)` utility which provides subset of `start-stop-daemon` functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, FreeBSD uses different kind of system. Just open up any other `/etc/rc.d` script to your favourite text editor and see examples from there.

Comment: Also check the handbook about FreeBSD rc scripts: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-rcd.html http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/configtuning-starting-services.html

Comment: +1 @dima.h There are plenty of FreeBSD experts lurking about [SF], so feel free to ask questions if you're having a rough time with the RC scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Check not only /etc/rc.d where system daemons scripts lives but also /usr/local/etc/rc.d where scripts for additional daemons like mysql or apache and such lives. They are rc shell scripts and, as usual, they have useful hints inside - how to make them startable when  system starts, how to setup additional params and many other funny stuff.